# Error opening video file logged using codec H264 or hevc using Opencv VideoCapture

Tags: opencv, video-capture, codec

I opened a `.avi` video file and written to a new `.avi` using cudacodec videowriter using h264 and hevc code. It is successfully logged. Again while opening the logged video file using video capture giving error.

```
Open could. Ot find decoder for codec_id=173
VideoIO/FFMPEG failed to initialize videoCapture
HandleMessage OpenCV | Gstreamer warning: your Gstreamer installation is missing a required plug-in
Unable to start pipeline
Gstream pipeline have not created
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.